# getimagesize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, getimagesize

I am using getimagesize to validate the image type but don't know how to write the script for multiple file.  Basically, I have a form that will allow upload of multiple image files like below.

```
  <input type="file" name="photo[]" class="file" />
  <input type="file" name="photo[]" class="file" />
  <input type="file" name="photo[]" class="file" />
```

Then I am using this to validate it and send via phpmailer.

```
<?php
ob_start();
require("class.phpmailer.php");

$errors = array();

if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
{
    $firstname           = sanitize($_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname           = sanitize($_POST['lastname']);
    $email                 = sanitize($_POST['email']);

    if (empty($firstname))
    {
        $errors['firstname'] = "Please provide first name.";
    }
    if (empty($lastname))
    {
        $errors['lastname'] = "Please provide last name.";
    }
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        $errors['email'] = "Please provide a valid email address.";
    }

    if (count($errors) === 0)
    {


$imageinfo = array();
  $my_files = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
  foreach($my_files as $single_file) {
  if(!empty($single_file)) {
  $imageinfo[$single_file] = getimagesize($single_file);
  if ($single_file['mime'] != 'image/png' && $single_file['mime'] != 'image/jpeg')
  { echo "Invalid Image File";
  exit();
  }  }
  }


foreach($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'] as $photo) 
if(!empty($photo)) {
$mail->AddAttachment($photo);


$message = 'some message';

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->SetFrom($email);
$mail->AddAddress($from);

$mail->Subject  = "Submitted";
$mail->Body     = $message;
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
}

$mail->Send();

header("Location: thankyou.php");
exit();     
}}

function sanitize($value)
{
    return trim(strip_tags($value, $problem=''));
}
?>
```

I am getting error message of **Warning: getimagesize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given**  I know this is because of my form is passing a array.  How do I change the script to work for multiple files/arrays?  please help.  thx.

Comment: Can you `echo '<pre>' . print_r($_FILES, true) . '</pre>';` just to check the FILES structure ?

Answer (score 5):

there are more than one file in `$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']` so its an array.

the `getimagesize()` designed to accept only one file.

so you need to pass each files to the function

```
$imageinfo = array();
$my_files = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
foreach($my_files as $single_file) {
  if(!empty($single_file)) {
    $imageinfo[$single_file] = getimagesize($single_file);
  }
}

print_r($imageinfo); // now you have info of all files in an array.
```

or you can try

```
$imageinfo0 = getimagesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][0]);
$imageinfo1 = getimagesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][1]);
$imageinfo2 = getimagesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][2]);
```

.... and so on..

Comment: The print looks like the file is attached but it is giving error of **Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Filename cannot be empty in** I need to have it required only 1 upload.  If the rest doesn't have anything upload is ok to send the email.  How do I do that?  thx so much for your help.

Comment: I changed the code as edited in my question. But it is not giving any message even when I attached a pdf file and there is no attachment in the email weather I attach image or non image. What did I do wrong? please help. thx.